# How to build an Alert Widget asp.net forms

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sharepoint, web-parts

I am working on a portal wich is hosted in Sharepoint 2007. I need to come up with a widget that will display certain messages. The widget to be visible from all pages of the portal. I would like something like the StackOverflow has for notifications of your score/badges with displaying it up on top of  every page. Is there a ready solution out there (jQuery/Ajax) that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Notify bar? Add it to the master page using SPD.

http://www.dmitri.me/misc/notify/